# swift (xcode) is it better to use optional or a temporary object?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When declaring an attribute that is set at the init stage, should it be set as an optional?
Or as a temporary object ?

See `grimoireMemento` attribute:

optional example :

```
class Kokoro{
    private var emot:String = ""
    var pain:[String:Int] = [:]
    private var grimoireMemento:GrimoireMemento?
    var toHeart:[String:String] = [:]
    var fromHeart:[String:String] = [:]
    var standBy:Bool = false
    init(absDictionaryDB: AbsDictionaryDB) {
        self.grimoireMemento = GrimoireMemento(absDictionaryDB: absDictionaryDB)
    }
    func getPain(biJuuName: String) -> Int {
        return pain[biJuuName] ?? 0
    }
    func getGrimoireMemento()->GrimoireMemento{
        return self.grimoireMemento!
    }
}
```

Versus a temporary object reference (which I assume will be disposed by the garbage collector):

```
class Kokoro{
    private var emot:String = ""
    var pain:[String:Int] = [:]
    var grimoireMemento:GrimoireMemento = GrimoireMemento(absDictionaryDB: AbsDictionaryDB())
    var toHeart:[String:String] = [:]
    var fromHeart:[String:String] = [:]
    var standBy:Bool = false
    init(absDictionaryDB: AbsDictionaryDB) {
        self.grimoireMemento = GrimoireMemento(absDictionaryDB: absDictionaryDB)
    }
    func getPain(biJuuName: String) -> Int {
        return pain[biJuuName] ?? 0
    }
}
```

For the `grimoireMemento` attribute which of the 2 examples should be used?

Comment: The first code is bad because it uses a force unwrap. The second code has an unnecessary assignment to `grimoireMemento` since it is assigned in the `init`. You can just say `var grimoireMemento:GrimoireMemento`

Comment: Swift does not use garbage collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [All of a class’s stored properties—including any properties the class
> inherits from its superclass—must be assigned an initial value during
> initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html).

That means you don't need to think about assigning a backup default outside of an initializer. Your two code snippets are not functionally similar but it seems like you want one of these.

```swift
private(set) var grimoireMemento: GrimoireMemento
```

```swift
let grimoireMemento: GrimoireMemento
```